# Is there any control over Carousel viewpager item position?

Tags: android

I have already implemented Carousel Viewpager  ...but I m stuck at one point.
There is 10 image item in ArrayList ...First 3 item (0,1,2 position) are showing and we can scroll horizontally one by one
What I want, When I click on first position i.e, 0 it should go position 1 and when I click on position 2, it should come position 1.
How can I achieve this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMgg7.jpg)

```
Method in mainActivity 

private void showDrinkList() {
    try {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int pageMargin = ((metrics.widthPixels / 3) * 2);
        pager.setPageMargin(-pageMargin);
        CarouselPagerAdapter adapter = new CarouselPagerAdapter(context,this.getChildFragmentManager(), this.getChildFragmentManager(), pager, drinkLists);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(adapter);
        if (drinkLists.size() > 1)
            pager.setCurrentItem(1);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        pager.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } }
Carousel Adapter - 
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Interpolator;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.List;
import ae.frink.android.R;
import ae.frink.android.app.customDialog.RedeemDialog;
import ae.frink.android.model.BeanDrinkImage;
import ae.frink.android.utils.FixedSpeedScroller;
import ae.frink.android.utils.ViewPagerCustomDuration;
public class CarouselPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    public final static float BIG_SCALE = 0.8f;
    private final static float SMALL_SCALE = 0.4f;
    private final static float DIFF_SCALE = BIG_SCALE - SMALL_SCALE;
    private FragmentManager context;
    private Context c;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private float scale;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    private List<BeanDrinkImage.DrinkList> drinkLists;
    private CarouselPagerAdapter adapter;
    //private ItemFragment itemFragment;

    public CarouselPagerAdapter(Context c, FragmentManager context, FragmentManager fm, ViewPager viewPager,
                                List<BeanDrinkImage.DrinkList> drinkLists) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragmentManager = fm;
        this.context = context;
         this.c = c;
      //  this.itemFragment = new ItemFragment(drinkLists);
        this.viewPager = viewPager;
        this.drinkLists = drinkLists;}

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // make the first pager bigger than others
        try {
            if (position == 0)    //BarInformationFrag.FIRST_PAGE)
                scale = SMALL_SCALE;
            else if(position == 1)
                scale = BIG_SCALE;
            else if(position == 2)
                scale = SMALL_SCALE;
            else
                scale = SMALL_SCALE;
         position = position % drinkLists.size();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("drinkSize", "....----" + drinkLists.size());
        // ItemFragment itemFragment = new ItemFragment();
        return ItemFragment.newInstance(context, position, scale, drinkLists);
    }
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
//        int count = 0;
//        try {
//            count = BarInformationFrag.count * BarInformationFrag.LOOPS;
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            // TODO: handle exception
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        return count;
        return drinkLists.size();
    }
  @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        try {
            if (positionOffset >= 0f && positionOffset <= 1f) {
                CarouselLinearLayout cur = getRootView(position);
                CarouselLinearLayout next = getRootView(position + 1);
                cur.setScaleBoth(BIG_SCALE - DIFF_SCALE * positionOffset);
                next.setScaleBoth(SMALL_SCALE + DIFF_SCALE * positionOffset);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
}
@Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
 }

    @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
    private CarouselLinearLayout getRootView(int position) {
        return (CarouselLinearLayout) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(this.getFragmentTag(position))
                .getView().findViewById(R.id.root_container);
    }
 private String getFragmentTag(int position) {
        return "android:switcher:" + viewPager.getId() + ":" + position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}




Carousel Linear Layout -

import android.content.Context;
  import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class CarouselLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    private float scale = CarouselPagerAdapter.BIG_SCALE;
//    private float scale = .5f;

    public CarouselLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CarouselLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setScaleBoth(float scale) {
        this.scale = scale;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // The main mechanism to display scale animation, you can customize it as your needs
        int w = this.getWidth();
        int h = this.getHeight();
         canvas.scale(scale, scale, w / 2, h / 2);

    }
}

item Fragment - 
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import ae.frink.android.R;
import ae.frink.android.app.customDialog.RedeemDialog;
import ae.frink.android.connection.ApiClient;
import ae.frink.android.model.BeanDrinkImage;

import static ae.frink.android.Carousel.CarouselPagerAdapter.viewPager;


public class ItemFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String POSITON = "position";
    private static final String SCALE = "scale";
    private static final String DRAWABLE_RESOURE = "resource";
    private static final String DRINK_LIST = "drinkList";
    private List<BeanDrinkImage.DrinkList> dL;
    private static final String IMAGE = "image";
    public ArrayList<Integer> imageArray;
    private Context context;
    private List<BeanDrinkImage.DrinkList> drinkLists;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;

    /* private int[] imageArray = new int[]{R.drawable.cocktail_lime_gin_fizz_1, R.drawable.cocktail_lime_gin_fizz_1,
             R.drawable.cocktail_lime_gin_fizz_1, R.drawable.cocktail_lime_gin_fizz_1, R.drawable.cocktail_lime_gin_fizz_1,
             R.drawable.cocktail_lime_gin_fizz_1, R.drawable.cocktail_lime_gin_fizz_1, R.drawable.cocktail_lime_gin_fizz_1,
             R.drawable.cocktail_lime_gin_fizz_1, R.drawable.cocktail_lime_gin_fizz_1};
 */

    public ItemFragment() {
    }

/*

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public ItemFragment(List<BeanDrinkImage.DrinkList> drinkLists) {
        this.drinkLists = drinkLists;
    }
*/


    public static Fragment newInstance(FragmentManager context, int pos, float scale, List<BeanDrinkImage.DrinkList> dL) {

        ItemFragment fr = new ItemFragment();

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(POSITON, pos);
        b.putFloat(SCALE, scale);
        b.putParcelableArrayList(DRINK_LIST, (ArrayList) dL);
        //drinkLists=dL;
        // this.context = context;
        // this.dL = dL;
        // b.putIntegerArrayList(IMAGE, imageArray);
        Log.e("drinkSize", "....+++"+dL.size());
        fr.setArguments(b);
        return fr;//frFragment.instantiate(context, ItemFragment.class.getName(), b);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWidthAndHeight();
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        context = getActivity();
        final int postion = this.getArguments().getInt(POSITON);
        float scale = this.getArguments().getFloat(SCALE);
        this.imageArray = this.getArguments().getIntegerArrayList(IMAGE);
        drinkLists = (ArrayList) this.getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(DRINK_LIST);

//         TODO 21 sep changes

//        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth / 3,
//                h/4);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth / 2,
                screenWidth/2);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        CarouselLinearLayout root = (CarouselLinearLayout) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.root_container);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.pagerImg);
        ImageView starImage = (ImageView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgStar);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        String imageUrl = "";
        try {
            Log.e("drinkSize", "...."+drinkLists.size());
            if (drinkLists.size() > 0) {
                imageUrl =  ApiClient.IMAGE_URL + drinkLists.get(postion).getImage();
                Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
                Log.e("drinkName", drinkLists.get(postion).getDrinkName());
                textView.setText(drinkLists.get(postion).getDrinkName());
                if (drinkLists.get(postion).getIs_recomended() == 1) {
                    starImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    starImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }



            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (getActivity() != null) {


                            RedeemDialog redeemDialog = new RedeemDialog(getActivity(), drinkLists, postion);
                            redeemDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                            redeemDialog.show();

                        // 12-march
                      /*  if (sharedPreferences.getString(CommonVar.IS_SUBSCRIBED, "0").equals("0")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please subscribe first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            RedeemDialog redeemDialog = new RedeemDialog(getActivity(), list, postion);
                            redeemDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                            redeemDialog.show();
                        }*/

                    }
                }
            });
            root.setScaleBoth(scale);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return linearLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Get device screen width and height
     */

    private void getWidthAndHeight() {
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        try {
            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "When I click on first position i.e, 0 it should go position 1 and when I click on position 2, it should come position 1. " are sure both clicks should take you the same positions. ?  and thats exactly what is problem is ?

Comment: Yes, For e.g I have attached an image, When  I click on Neptune (position 0), it should come in the center, place of Classic Mojito (position 1). When I click on Romulus (position 2) It should go come to the center.

Comment: Hello. You can detect the clicks on your individual items and get back exactly which one was clicked. Then you can easily scroll to that position. We could help you more if you would say what did you try and what went wrong (and of course post the code as well).

Comment: @cylon...I had uploaded my code ..You can check now . Thank in advance

Comment: If anyone knows, Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (position == 0) {
  scale = SMALL_SCALE;}
            else if(position == 1){

                scale = BIG_SCALE;
}
            else if(position == 2)
  {
              scale = SMALL_SCALE;
}
            else{

                scale = SMALL_SCALE;
}
```

Comment: FYI: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. You may want to improve it by explaining how this code answers OP's question.